# Substract 2 datetimes

Tags: php

I need to substract 2 datetimes, I tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work:

```
$startime = $historial->getStarttime(); //Datetime
$endtime  = $historial->getEndtime();   //Datetime
$mytime = $endtime - $startime;
```

I also tried with `strtotime()`, `date()`...

Any help or clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $datetime1 = new \DateTime('2009-10-11');
    $datetime2 = new \DateTime('2009-10-13');
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $datetime1->sub($interval);

    echo $datetime1->format("Y-m-d"); // 2009-10-09
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at diff() method of DateTime object: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
<?php
$interval = $startTime->diff($endTime);
```

It returns a DateInterval method that you can format as you want: http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

```
<?php
echo $interval->format('%d days');
```

Answer (score 1):

The substraction operator doesn't work like that, you'll need [DateTime::diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
$diff = $starttime->diff($endtime);
```

This shall return a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) instance, that you can output in whatever [format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) you want.